# Hosting Office Web Add-in as Azure Static Web App and Azure Function App - possible?

Tags: azure-functions, office-addins, azure-static-web-app, azure-private-link

We are contemplating hosting an Office Web Add-in using the following components

- Office Web Add-in Web Application: Azure Static Web App on Standard Plan with Private Link enabled, thereby restricting public access, with Active Directory Authentication enabled for SSO
- Web Application Backend API: Azure Function App on Premium Plan, also with Private Link enabled, with CORS enabled for Azure Static Web App access via XMLHttpRequest2

We would like users to be able to load the Web Application from Excel desktop and Excel online.

Considering Office Web Add-in is essentially an IFRAME loading any web application that is accessible to user, we imagine these hosting strategies is feasible?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/functions-bring-your-own#security-constraints), it will not be possible to integrate Azure Static Web App with an Azure Function App that utilises private link to restrict access

> Required public accessibility: An existing Functions app needs to not
> apply the following security configurations.
>
> Restricting the IP address of the Functions app.
>
> Restricting traffic through private link or service endpoints.